# each function in jquery condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have different items in select menu list. For each item I want to do some different task (one for chocolate one for taffy likewise). how do i do this? The each function does the same task for every item

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div { color:red; }
 </style>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <select name="sweets" multiple="multiple">
 <option id="ch">Chocolate</option>
 <option selected="selected">Candy</option>

<option>Taffy</option>
<option selected="selected">Caramel</option>
<option>Fudge</option>
<option>Cookie</option>

 </select>
 <div></div>
 <script>
 $("select").change(function () {
 var str = "";
 $("select.#ch option:selected").each(function () {
        str += $(this).text() + " ";
  });
 $("div").text(str);
 })
 .change();
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Problem here -> `select.#ch`??

Comment: If you got a solution, please post it. Don't edit out your question in case it helps people in the future!

Answer (score 7):

You have selector error in `select.#ch`, so it should be either `select > option:selected`, or:

```
$("option:selected", this).each(function() {
    str += $(this).text() + " ";
});
```

However I'd rewrite the code in a following way:

```
$("select").change(function () {
    var str = $("option:selected", this).map(function() {
        return this.innerHTML;
    }).get().join(" ");

    $("div").text(str);
}).change();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/MpjjE/

Comment: I want different action for different selection.. actually i have a php file to query out the image associated with the selected item. I need to call that file and display the image here, once user selects an item. How should i do this?

Comment: @user2003663 You should read about Ajax. The solution can be a bit more complicated.

Comment: I know how to use ajax, but here i need the url of the image. if php file echoes back the url, how do i receive it?